# What's the stance on Class-specific tags to questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

What is the stance over class-specific tags in questions?  Clearly — for example — it would be best to have [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) (an API/Framework) than [nsarray](/questions/tagged/nsarray) (a class defined within).

The real question is, ***should class-specific tags be removed***?  APIs have hundreds of class names. Considering many Framework & APIs are covered here, I imagine the community would try to keep tag names fairly low.

I don't want to insult anyone nor come over as an over-zealous editor nor start an edit-war by removing tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, class-specific tags should not be removed.  However, if there are questions tagged [nsarray](/questions/tagged/nsarray) that don't have the [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) tag, the latter tag should be added.  We don't need to keep the overall number of tag names low if the tags give extra information.

Comment: I am thinking about creating a "qtcore" tag on stackoverflow, so this answer is useful to me to get some feedback about such ideas. We have had class tags, but nothing for the module providing those. I was considering replacing the class tags initially with the module, but perhaps it is just better to add the module tag then, isn't it?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yes, I would just add the module name tag and leave the class name tag in place.

Comment: Thanks. FYI: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198592/creating-a-qtcore-tag